# having difficulty trying to use .find() and .children inside a mini object of selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im basically trying to move away from the procedural js approach so trying to use objects a lot more. I've set up an object within my overall object to cache selectors and set up variables etc but I seem to be having problems. Currently I get 2 errors when I run this code telling me that both .length and .children are undefined. Can someone explain the proper method of setting these up so the jquery methods can be used?

JS

```
var bop = {

        els: {
           // cache selectors ...
            grid: $( '#grid' ),
            box: this.grid.children(),
            box_l: this.box.length,
            start_btn: $( '#start' ),
            counter: $( '#counter' ),
            sequence: 5            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you expect that `this` will refer to the under-construction object you're building with the object literal, then that's your problem. JavaScript doesn't work that way.

You can do this:

```
var bop = {
 els: {
   grid: $('#grid'),
   // ...
 }
};

bop.els.box = box.els.grid.children();
// etc
```

The `this` reference is all about function calls and really has nothing to do with objects, or not as much as you might think it does if you come from a C++/C#/Java background.

Answer (score 2):

When using `this` inside a literal object, it doesn't refer to the object that is being created, it still is the same as in the code outside the literal object.

Answer (score 1):

If you badly wanna use `this` then, change your caching object to

```
els: {
           // cache selectors ...
            grid: $( '#grid' ),
            box: function(){
                   return this.grid.children()
            },
            box_l: function(){
                  return this.box().length
            },
            start_btn: $( '#start' ),
            counter: $( '#counter' ),
            sequence: 5            
        }
```

Other wise make sure you refer to `$( '#grid' )` when you use the `box` and `box_1` properties.

On a side note, **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/uT5jY/)** fiddle will help you understand why your `this` doesnt work the way you thought it'd work. Cheers.